# Dropdown Search Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a dropdown search selector to open content based off of a selection, whether it is through the search function or selection from drop down, however I can't get the selector to work properly.

EDIT:

I've decided to use select2 instead of a custom built dropdown search selector. With this, I had to use the reference the direct links to the CSS and JS files. For some reason referencing the files locally isn't working. The new issue I'm having is when I select one option, both options are displayed. Where am I messing this up at?

EDITTED CODE:

See below code for what I have already attempted:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="../CSS/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../JS/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../JS/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<style>
@font-face {
 font-family:"Poppins";
 src: url("../Font/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.woff") format('woff');
 font-weight: 600;
}
html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; 
 overflow: hidden;
}

.video_container {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 65vw;
 height: 80vh;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 1%;
}

.select_div_container {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30vw;
 height: 80vh;
 float: left;
 postion: fixed;
}

.select_div_desc {
 width: 75%;
 height: 40vh;
 overflow: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.video_iframe, .video_span {
 display: none;  
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
 .select_div_container {width: 100%; height: 45vh;}
 .select_div_desc {width: 100%; height: 60%;}
 .video_container {width: 100%; height: 40vh;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
     
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1401px) and (max-width: 1920px) {

}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.dropped').select2();
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".dropped").change(function() {
         var val= $(this).find("option a").attr('name');
         $(".video_iframe").show("slow");
         $(".video_span").show("slow");
         $("#"+val).show("slow");
         $("."+val).show("slow");
     });    
 });   
</script>
</head>
<body>
     
<div class="select_div_container"><select class="dropped" style="width: 100%;" > <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select a Training Video</option><optgroup label="DROPPER"><option><a name="video_01">VIDEO#1</a></option><option><a name="video_02">VIDEO #2</a></option></optgroup></select><br><br><br><br><div class="select_div_desc"><span class="video_span" class="video_01">VIDEO #1 DESCRIPTION</span><span class="video_span" class="video_02">VIDEO #2 DESCRIPTION</span></div></div>

<div class="video_container">
 <iframe class="video_iframe" id="video_01"  src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/d9zEho-gQd9zE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 <iframe class="video_iframe" id="video_02" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/_9zEhpAYoYo-g" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the selector 'not working properly?'

Comment: I tried ur code, and <select> work as it should. what's wrong here ?

Comment: it is not displaying the '.video_frame' div container or the iframe inside of it

Answer (score 0):

The div "video_frame" and iframe are not showing based on the select class option being selected.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you will have to replace your youtube situation yourself. Otherwise I have fixed everything for you so that the jQuery works properly.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Drop Test</title>
        <style>
            .video_frame {
                background: #efefef;
                width: 50%;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                height: 75%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Bootstrap Select demo</h1>


            <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-info" multiple data-max-options="3" data-live-search="true">
                <optgroup label="Test">
                    <option id="vdo1" value="1">Test</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>

        </div>


        <br><br>
        <div class="video_frame">
            <div style="width:40%;min-height:200px;"></div>
        </div>

        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $(".video_frame").hide();

                $(".selectpicker optgroup option").click(function () {
                    $(".video_frame").show("slow");
                    var val = $(this).find("optgroup option").attr('value');
                    $("#" + val).show("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just replace the styled div with your iframe.

**The Major problem** was that your css was set to not display your video. trying to show() it does not affect css display. You need to hide() it onload, and show() it when it is selected.

Another Solution would be to to use a

.css('display', 'none') onload

and

.css('display', 'inline-block') onselect

You would still need to remove "display:none;" from the css.

There are likely other solutions as well.